# Compare time ignoring last 3 digits of second fraction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have tests that ensure a timestamp does not change.  They pass in my local environment but fail on the build.  It has something to do with the value being returned for 'updated_at' is changing the last 3 digits of the second fraction to 0.  Here is an example of the failures:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: 
expected: 2015-01-06 10:16:29.948655841 -0500
     got: 2015-01-06 10:16:29.948655000 -0500

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: 
expected: 2015-01-06 10:16:31.236196108 -0500
     got: 2015-01-06 10:16:31.236196000 -0500
```

How can I build the assertion to ignore those last 3 digits?  Is there a function of time that just compares the time, say to the hundreds place of the fraction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need milliseconds at all? If not, just disregard them using time.change(:usec => 0). If you need more precision while accounting for this difference, you may have to start getting creative. Alternately just change your test to ensure the timestamps are within a tolerance.

Comment: @JonStory, I need milliseconds because the test is for timestamp updating and the tests run very quickly.

Comment: Okay, my knowledge of Ruby isn't great but I'd be tempted to (unless someone pops up with a simpler solution) subtract the timestamps from each other (assuming Ruby allows this) and compare the absolute values. eg abs(t1-t2) < 0.0000001 would check that the timestamps are within three 100millionth's of each other. Or whatever that works out as.

Comment: I think that is a solution worth trying.

Comment: @JonStory, to follow up I was still getting the same inaccuracy errors, just in another format.  It is not worth the time to rebuild the app just to test this trivial stuff, so I removed the tests.

Answer (score 4):

When working with float numbers, usually you should use the `be_within` matcher: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher

This way, you can define the precision in which you want to compare the values:

```rb
expect(updated_at).to be_within(0.000001).of(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby maintains a greater precision than the database (PostgreSQL in my case).

When the value is read back from the database, it’s preserved to fewer digits after the decimal.

There two ways of solving this:

1. Use `to_i` to convert to UNIX time.

   ```
   expect(user.updated_at.to_i).to eq(new_updated_at.to_i)
   ```

   To further help with this, you may create a helper in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

   ```
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312010/1177636
    RSpec::Matchers.define :eq_time do |expected|
      match do |actual|
        expected.to_i == actual.to_i
      end
    end
   ```

   Then use it as

   ```
   expect(user.updated_at).to eq_time(new_updated_at)
   ```
2. Use RSpec's `be_within` matcher.

   https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher

   ```
   expect(user.updated_at).to be_within(0.001.seconds).of(new_updated_at)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, defining another matcher would be probably the cleanest way of doing that. That's what I defined in our code base for example.

```rb
# Matcher to match time more loosely, it matches to the second
#
RSpec::Matchers.define :match_time do |expected_time|
  match do |actual_time|
    expected_time.change(usec: 0) == actual_time.change(usec: 0)
  end

  failure_message do |actual_time|
    "Expected #{expected_time} to match #{actual_time} to the second"
  end

  diffable
end
```

Then use it as

```rb
expect(this_time).to match_time(that_time)
```

When erroring

```
  1) Example description
     Failure/Error:
       expect(this_time).to match_time(that_time)

       Expected 2022-07-05 20:22:47 UTC to match 2023-07-05 20:22:47 UTC to the second
       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -Tue, 05 Jul 2022 20:22:47 UTC +00:00
       +Wed, 05 Jul 2023 20:22:47 UTC +00:00
```